# How to improve CNN model?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, classification, conv-neural-network

My question sounds abstract question but I am wondering how people train CNN models.

Here is my case.

I have been playing around with a CNN model trying to classify given images into 3 categories. The dataset is balanced.
An image is (12, 12, 4) and is a heatmap encoded time-series, and I do not think that using data augmentation is useful in this case because it may not make sense if I flip it horizontally or vertically, if I rotate them, etc.

The best result I got was about 52% of acc from validation set and about 38% from testset.

I started implementing a very simple model that has 2 Conv layers without pooling layers in order to avoid the truncation of the characteristics of the time series.
And added Dense layers one is for hidden and the other is for the output layer.

I have tested some techniques that could help to improve its performance such as LR scheduler, changing different activation functions and optimizers but haven got tiny improvements.

Here is what I want to ask people who have experience in CNN.

- In this situation that I mentioned above, what things would you do at first? Tuning hyperparameters would be an option, but how would you tune them up? how would you choose parameters you would tune-up?
- How do you choose a model's architecture? Like the number of layers, the number of neurons in each layer, and how do you decide which type of layer you use?
- Is there any blog posts or papers related to my question?

If anyone has advice, I would be grateful to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best advice would be looking at the State of the art and see if you can find anything useful. I don't think you will be the first one having this kind of input. Find something that is at least similar and take it as a basis.

Coming up with a architecture completely on your own is time consuming and requires a huge amount of resources. You can do this if you already have experience or some big gpu cluster, if not it is better to learn form the experience others.

Just go to google scholar and search for keywords like "time series" "deep learning" "cnn". Maybe you are lucky and find a nice overview paper, which always help tremendously, to get some orientation.

Comment: I appreciate your advice. I will be finding papers in which training model on similar data to mine and will implement its architecture and parameters that could fit my data.

Answer (score 0):

try to use known CNN's such VGG16, VGG19, ResNetor others, then try to optimize the parameters using metaheuristic optimizers.